# Can not rename the file using Angular.js and ng-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I need one help.I can not rename my filename using `ng-file-upload` in angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

```
<input type="file"  data-size="lg" name="bannerimage2" id="imagefile2"  ng-model="imagefile2" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB"   custom-on-change="uploadFile1" ngf-select="onFileSelect('bannerimage2',$file);" >
```

My controller side code is given below.

```
$scope.onFileSelect = function(name,$files) {
        //console.log('select',name,$files);
        switch(name){
            case 'bannerimage2':
               fileURL1=$files;
               $scope.image2='';
               break;
        }
    }

var file1=fileURL1;
$scope.prefix="REG";
$scope.timestamp =$filter('date')(new Date ,'yyyyMMddHHmmss');
var a = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);
a = a.toString().substring(0, 4);
$scope.secondImage=$scope.prefix+"_"+$scope.timestamp+a+"_"+file1.name;
file1.name=$scope.secondImage;
var data={'image':file1};
fileData.push(data);
 console.log('file data',fileData);
```

In console message when i am checking for new file name but its not showing any new name.Here i need to replace the old name with new created file name.Please help me.

Comment: Use `Upload.rename()` read the docs.

Comment: yes,by using that i solved my problem.